# What makes a better CPU more expensive?

Tags: cpu

Example:
I've a i5-3570k in my computer. ARK suggested price is $235.00

I've gone for a i7-3770k, but it's way more expensive, $342.00

Then you have a Intel Celeron G1820 for only $42.00

What makes a CPU expensive? I mean it's the same material, same technique.
I know this comparision is like comparising how much sand it needed, but what does it make to rise the price?

Comment: Its based on the number of transistors.  Its also the fact there are less of the higher performance products made due to how the manufacturing process works.

Comment: sometimes its all about marketing and line differentiation. each general type of device has a number of market-established price points, and most vendors try to have a model available at each point at all times. this is part of why older parts never get cheaper than the cheapest product the company had in that line last month or last year, or 3 years ago, or even last decade. Most consumer goods these days are priced for what the market will pay, with less emphasis on the old `price = (cost + overhead + profit expectation + retailer mark-up)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets take a look a fictional company that makes CPUs. Or any kind of processing chip, really, but we'll stick to CPUs for demonstration purposes. Now, this company, we'll call it, say, Armtel, is a bit of an oddball in that it has a strange disinterest in profit. It's solely focused on minimizing losses. And, somehow, they've managed to design a new product without spending any money on research, development, factory reconfiguration, or any other fixed costs, so the only losses they have to recuperate are the costs it takes to get each CPU from raw materials to the working product.

---

## Why CPUs might cost more than the materials within them.

So this fancy new CPU, the Z9001, which wipes the floor with the competition in both performance and efficiency, let's say it costs $100 to produce. Great, so let's set the price to $100 and we're done. Except, thanks to manufacturing defects, not all the produced chips function as well as they're supposed to. Now Armtel could advertise all their CPUs with the characteristics of the worst, but then they'd be underperforming their competitors' $2 products. Oh, and that's not including the chips that don't work at all. Good luck selling those for any price.

The alternative is to only sell the chips that can perform to spec, and simply charge more to make up for the unsellable junk. Well, what should the higher price be? That depends on what percentage of chips are defective. Now, on a slight tangent, the Z9001 is a big chip. Armtel had to pack in a lot of transistors into this thing with some pretty clever logic in order to achieve their performance targets. The unfortunate things about manufacturing big chips are that you can fit much fewer on each silicon wafer, and a much higher percentage of them are defective. Figure 3-10 on page 3-7 in [this pdf](http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/CEICM/SECTION3.pdf) is a fantastic diagram of why big chips grow more costly faster than their area. In fact, let's borrow the middle size from that diagram. Thus, Armtel can fit four Z9001 dice on a wafer, but only 25%, or one is actually completely free of defects, on average. For convenience, we'll ignore the always unusable silicon around the edges.

So for each sellable die, Armtel has three unsellable dice, for a total cost of $400. In order to reach their goal of breaking even, the Z9001 has to cost $400. Success! And all is well with Armtel.

Until Al Zane, the CEO of Armtel gets tired of having the view out of his hundredth floor office blocked by the growing mountain of defective chips.

---

## Why CPUs from the same design have different prices.

Armtel could just dump all these defective chips in a landfill, but that would mildly annoy the environment protection groups. Also, Al just happens to live next door to the president of one of those groups and Al is 99% certain that that president is also an axe murderer. So he'd much prefer to remain environmentally friendly lest he find himself unable to chop wood some day.

Recycling is another possibility, but that would take a lot more effort than the other option: selling them.

Most of the defective chips do work, at least in some capacity. Some might have a core or five that just don't work, or maybe they just won't remain stable at 10GHz for some reason, but drop them down to a mere 8GHz and everything is dandy. Looking at his competitors' prices and sales numbers, it seems there is something of a market for CPUs that cost less than $400, and of course, all of Armtel's competitors's chips are pitiful compared to the Z9001, so maybe not everyone needs all that performance.

So Armtel starts measuring the performance of the defective chips a bit more closely, and notices about 33% of them seem to be perfectly fine running at 7.5GHz with only 12 cores active. Compared to the fully operational Z9001 with 16 cores racing along at 10GHz and we've got 75% of the cores times 75% of the clock speed gives roughly 56.25% of the performance (There are many performance factors I'm ignoring here, but this is a good enough estimation for the fictional Armtel here).

Okay, so Armtel has a new product which they're calling the Z8001. What should they price it at? They can't price it the same as the Z9001, because they're pretty sure nobody is going to pay the same price for an inferior CPU. Pricing it higher results in the same amount of sales: zero. So less is the only way to go. How much less? Let's try using the approximate performance ratio: $400 x 56.25% = $225

Great, now Armtel is selling 50% of the chips they're producing instead of 25%. But there's a problem. Remember back in the beginning that I mentioned that Armtel is an oddball business that dislikes profit? Well, they now are spending $400 for every four dice they make, and selling two of them, one at $400 and one at $225.

```
$400 + $225 - $400 = +$225
```

---

## How companies selling partially defective (but still reliably functional) chips can benefit you.

+$225 is clearly more than $0 and that's a problem that Al is determined to fix. Clearly $400 and $225 are now too much to charge. How much should Armtel be charging to meet their desired break even point? If the Z9001 costs `x` and the Z8001 costs `y`, then these equations give us our answers:

```
$400 = x + y
y = .5625x
```

[Throwing these through a calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400%3Dx%2By%2C%20y%3D.5625x) tells us the Z9001 should be priced at $256 and the Z8001 at $144. That's a 36% discount for the Z9001, and for those who don't need the full capabilities of the top CPU, the Z8001 is 64% less than the original Z9001 price. Not too shabby since all they did was start selling some not quite perfect, but still mostly functional chips. Just for fun, what if Armtel scrounged up another 25% of their chips and started selling the Z7001 for 56.25% of the performance and price of the Z8001? Running

```
$400 = x + y + z
y = .5625x
z = .5625y
```

[through a calculator gives prices of](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400%3Dx%2By%2Bz%2C%20y%3D.5625x%2C%20z%3D.5625y)

```
Z9001 = $212.89
Z8001 = $119.75
Z7001 = $67.36
```

Look at that, prices dropped again, and the Z7001 is actually being sold below cost, yet Armtel is still reaching their goal of breaking even.

---

## But what about the real world, where companies actually want to profit? And also have other costs?

Well, I don't work for any CPU or other chip makers, so I can't give you any hard numbers. But that first price point that Armtel had the Z8001? A profit-seeking company might be thrilled about that, but it might still be in their interest to lower prices. Armtel's final price points for just the Z9001 and Z8001 (no Z7001), would be the approximate asymptotic minimums, assuming they can successfully sell at those prices.

Chances are they would want prices a bit higher, but not necessarily back up to the original prices. The less expensive the chips are, the more they can sell, and they want to maximize total profits, not marginal profits (profit per unit). As for a real world Z7001, well, that's just an effort to minimize losses. Selling something that costs $100 for only $67 is a $33 loss, but that's a lot better than the $100 loss of not selling it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Marketing.  They want to sell products from entry-level to enthusiast.

The majority of the cost in research & development, not manufacturing.  If you break down the manufacturing costs, most of it is the factory, not the materials.